# How do set UserScript in Microsoft Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, userjs

How do i can install my user.js into Microsoft Edge 38.14 in Windows 10 Mobile Enterprise? 
Perhaps someone has link to a manual.

Answer (score 1):

Try to download the Tampermonkey extension from Windows store.

[Tampermonkey](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/tampermonkey/9nblggh5162s?rtc=1#activetab=pivot:overviewtab)

It can help you to install user.js on Edge.

[Installing Userscripts](https://openuserjs.org/about/Tampermonkey-for-Edge)

Generally it works for PC, You can have a try on Windows 10 Mobile Enterprise.

If MS Edge in Windows 10 Mobile Enterprise does not support to install extension then at present it will not be possible for you to install user.js

Other then that I did not get any ways or manuals to install user.js on Windows 10 Mobile Enterprise.

You can post this question on Windows 10 Mobile Enterprise support forum to check whether they are available with any solution or not.

Comment: Thank you friend a lot.